# Get the selected ID from jEasyUI combogrid and insert into datagrid second field

Tags: jquery, jquery-easyui

Basically, I'm having a **easyui-datagrid** with first column of combogrid, 2nd column is not an entry field, and subsequent columns.
Here is the Code

```
<table id="dg-form" class="easyui-datagrid" title="Details" style="width:100%;height:300px;" data-options="singleSelect: true, toolbar: '#tb', method: 'get', onClickRow: onClickRow">
  <thead>
    <tr>
       <th id="cc" data-options="field:'itemid',width:300, 
          editor: {
            type:'combogrid', options:{
            panelWidth:450,
            delay : 800,
            mode : 'remote',
            idField:'ITEM_CODE',
            textField:'ITEM_CODE',
            method:'post',
            url:'server_setup.php',
            required:true,
            loadMsg: 'Searching...',
            columns:[[
              {field:'ITEM_CODE',title:'ITEM_CODE',width:100},
              {field:'ITEM_NAME',title:'ITEM_NAME',width:200},
              {field:'QOH',title:'QOH',width:50}
            ]]
          }}">
      Item Code</th>

      <th data-options="field:'itemname',width:80,align:'left'">Item Name</th>
      <th data-options="field:'qty',width:80,align:'right',editor:{type:'numberbox',options:{precision:1}}">Qty</th>
      <th data-options="field:'remarks',width:250,editor:'text'">Remarks</th>
      <th data-options="field:'action',width:250,editor:'text'">Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

When user type in the 'Item Code' field, it will trigger an AJAX call to the server to obtain the data, and when the user click on the combogrid selection, the *ItemCode* will be inserted into my first column. I want the *ItemName* to be populated in second column at the same time, how can i achieve that? I've tried onSelect, onClick and few others and no success. For example, the onSelect trigger before user key in the item code.

Comment: Okay, I've able to capture the value during onChange event, by adding this onChange: function(row){ alert (row); } into the editor, but how can i get this value and replace it on my second column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manage to solve my own issue.
Here is the code to share out.

```
function onSelect(index, row) 
{
    console.log (row.ITEM_CODE);
        var ed = $("#dg-form").datagrid("getEditor", {index:editIndex,field:"itemCode"});
        $(ed.target).val(row.ITEM_CODE);
}
```